# Click on button == button appears in random location

Tags: android, xamarin

Hello guys I'm doing a game where you have to click 10times in a row on a button which after every click appears on random location. So for this i need to find height and width of device. I will try to do it for android, because as I googled for IOS completely different code. So for this I will do it:

```
 public static int ScreenHeight { get; set; }
 public static int ScreenWidth { get; set; }
 App.ScreenHeight = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
 App.ScreenWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
```

So here I need to know what App has to be there? Form name in Android Xamarin Or layout name or my project's app name. The next thing i need help is to give button location of my generated random locations I googled a lot so it depends on what method I'm using to generate the  locations. :

```
Random xLoc = new Random();
Random yLoc = new Random();
int realXLoc;
int realYLoc;
realXLoc = xLoc.Next(1, ScreenWidth);
realYLoc = xLoc.Next(1, ScreenHeight);
```

Basically what I'm trying to ask is a piece of code which converts my ideas to reality. Sincerely Rectinho.

Comment: I really struggle to understand your first question. What do you mean with "So here I need to know what App has to be there? Form name in Android Xamarin Or layout name or my project's app name."? For the second one instead, show first what you've tried, it does not depend on how you generate the positions! (It should be a property that every time is set, with the OnPropertyChanged, triggers the new location of the button)

Comment: Add. this place gets underlined so something is wrong here, and I don't really understand what wrong I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not getting the right ScreenHeight and ScreenWidth. You could try to use [`DisplayMetrics`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Util.DisplayMetrics/) class.

For example:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    int ScreenHeight;
    int ScreenWidth;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click += Button_Click;

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(displayMetrics);
        ScreenHeight = displayMetrics.HeightPixels;
        ScreenWidth = displayMetrics.WidthPixels;
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Random xLoc = new Random();
        Random yLoc = new Random();
        int realXLoc;
        int realYLoc;
        Button button = sender as Button;
        realXLoc = xLoc.Next(1, ScreenWidth- button.Width);
        realYLoc = xLoc.Next(1, ScreenHeight - button.Height);
        button.SetX(realXLoc);
        button.SetY(realYLoc);
    }
}
```

And the result:
[image]